# code execution is not going inside react function

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-component

When i try to call auth.isauthenticated(), execution flow is not going inside componentDidMount() function. It skips all code inside of componentDidMount() and goes directly to isAuthenticated function. this is the complete flow of my code.

```
import { Redirect, Route } from "react-router";
import auth from "./auth";

const ProtectedRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest} ) => {
    return ( 
        <Route  {...rest} render={
            (props) =>{
                if(auth.isAuthenticated()){
                    return <Component {...props} />
                }
                else{
                    return <Redirect to='/login' />
                }
            }
        } />
     );
}
 
export default ProtectedRoute;

import axios from 'axios'
import React from 'react';
import {constants} from './script/constant';

class Auth extends React.Component{

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = { 
            authenticated: false
        };
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
        .then(res => {
            const userData = res.data;
            if(userData === ""){
                this.setState({authenticated: false});
                console.log("falseapi");
            }
            else{
                this.setState({authenticated:true});  
                console.log("trueapi");
            }            
        })  
    };
    isAuthenticated(){
        return this.state.authenticated;
    }

}
export default new Auth();
```

Comment: I don't see you calling `isAuthenticated` anywhere. Where is that happening?

Comment: @samuei, I have edited the above code and included the missing code.

Comment: Thank you. It doesn't look like you're ever inserting Auth into your DOM tree, which is when componentDidMount runs.

Comment: Thank you @samuei. I am new to react i dont know much , can you give me some reference where i can find solution to releated problem.

Comment: Long story short, you should look up the lifecycle of a component in react to learn more. 

To solve your specific problem, you should convert Auth into a regular Javascript object instead, since it has nothing to render.